# AMD Ryzen R7 5700G APU OpenCL on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Tags: 20.04, amd-graphics, amdgpu, opencl

I've just built a PC with a Ryzen R7 5700G APU, and it's working well under Ubuntu 20.04.3 except for the fact that I can't get OpenCL to work.

So far I've mostly tried installing AMDGPU and AMDGPU Pro, and have tried releases 21.30, 21.20, and 21.10, and have tried these on both Ubuntu 20.04.3 and 20.04.2. I also tried AMDGPU and AMDGPU Pro 20.30 with Ubuntu 20.04.1. But no luck with any of these, regardless of if headless or not headless (though not headless breaks the graphics), regardless of AMDGPU or AMDGPU Pro, and regardless of pal, legacy, or rocr. Also tried ROCm, which also failed to work.

With clinfo I can see that there is one platform (the APU), but no devices, thus it isn't usable for any apps that require OpenCL devices. The APU otherwise seems to be working well under Ubuntu 20.04.3 - WebGL in Firefox and Chrome works, and the system recognizes it (albeit as Renoir rather than Cezanne).

If anyone's been in the same situation and managed to get their Cezanne APU graphics working with Ubuntu, I'd love to hear about what worked for you! Or if anyone has any ideas of what to try, or if I just need to wait for future AMDGPU or Ubuntu updates.

Comment: I'm in the same exact boat. OpenGL and WebGL work fine but I can't seem to get Vulkan to work. I haven't tried OpenCL yet, can you name an app that uses OpenCL so I can give it a try? I know the Ryzen 7 5700g just came out last month so I am being patient. I have a dual boot setup with Windows 10 but I would like to exclusively use Ubuntu 100% of the time when I get the APU working correctly. Unfortunately due to the chip shortage I cannot afford a discrete GPU at this time so I am relying on the APU for all of my graphics needs. I'm currently using the latest 21.30 release which is the only o

Comment: Sorry to hear you're also having this issue - unfortunately I've yet to get it working. The OpenCL application I'd like to use is Blender. Good luck with getting it working for you - if I figure it out I'll let you know.

Comment: Did you succeed meanwhile? If there's a "straight and easy way" (preferably without proprietay parts), I'd like to use that for Folding@Home – which detects the GU but no OpenCL support.

Comment: OpenCL works for me after I rebooted once I installed the amdgpu release 21.40 on my ubuntu 20.04 system (5700G). I'm not running a gui, my system is setup `sudo systemctl set-default multi-user`. I haven't tried using the console to launch the gui or a `sudo systemctl set-default graphical` boot.